# Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to add my contact form details to my firebase database but I got error.
I run this project in expo. In web version, data is going to firebase but in mobile version
I am facing this error. Please help me I don't know why this error was coming.  ㅤㅤ

Error

> FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field title in document posts/5TT9b7F0lkqxoivmsIiH)).

Here's my code:
**Contact form.js**

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView,TextInput,Button } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import colors from '../colors';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
//import { TextInput } from "react-native-web";
import { auth, database } from '../config/firebase';
import {collection,addDoc,orderBy,query,onSnapshot} from 'firebase/firestore';

const catImageUrl = "https://i.pravatar.cc/300";

const Home = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [name,setName ] =useState();
    const [email,setEmail ] =useState();
    const [message,setMessage] =useState();
    
    const userCollectionRef = collection(database,'contactdata') 
    const handleSubmit = ()=>{
        addDoc(userCollectionRef,{
            name : name || null,
            email :email || null ,
            message: message || null

        });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerLeft: () => (
                <FontAwesome name="home" size={25} color={'#1C64D1'} style={{marginLeft: 15}}/>

            ),
            headerRight: () => (
                <FontAwesome name="user" size={24} color={'#1C64D1'} style={{marginRight: 25}}/>
            ),
        });
    }, [navigation]);


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.form}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Complaint Form</Text>
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 20 }}>Name</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} onChange={(event)=>{
            setName(event.target.value)
          }} />

          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 20 }}>Name</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} onChange={(event)=>{
            setEmail(event.target.value)
          }} />

          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 20 }}>Name</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} onChange={(event)=>{
            setMessage(event.target.value)
          }}/>

        <Button title="Press mee" onPress={handleSubmit} color={colors.primary}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
        
        
      </View>
    );
    };

    export default Home;
    

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            flexDirection:"column",
          },
        container1: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this code? The message mentions a `posts` collection, but none of the code you shared writes to a collection of that name.